# Profile Fields in D7?

Tags: 7, users

How do you add fields to a user in Drupal 7 for say, first and last name? I see that Profile is deprecated, is there an easy way to do this without using Content Profile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can directly add fields to users (at admin/config/people/accounts/fields) if that's all you need. You can set for each field if it should show up on the registration form.

What [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) allows *additionally* is to create multiple profiles for each user, similar to the categorization feature of the core profile.module.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2).

Comment: Can this add fields to registration and account pages? Also usable with Views?